# How to programmatically quit mainloop via a tkinter canvas Button

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My program generates several graphs one at a time and each has a quit button.
The program pauses in `mainloop` until I press the button, then generates the next graph.

I would like a way to programmatically press or invoke the action associated to that button, in this case `root.quit()`

I have tried calling `invoke()` on the button but this doesn't work. My feeling is that the event is lost before `mainloop` is started.

```
from tkinter import * 

pause = False # passed in as an arg

root = Tk()
root.title(name)

canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg = 'white') 
canvas.pack()

quit = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
quit.pack()

# make sure everything is drawn
canvas.update()        

if not pause:
    # Invoke the button event so we can draw the next graph or exit
    quit.invoke()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the problem was with the event being lost and `mainloop` blocking so I used the `pause` arg to determine when to run `mainloop`, i.e. on the last graph.

See [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

All graphs are displayed and when you press Quit on any window all windows disappear and the program ends.

If there is a better way to do this please let me know, but this works.

```
root = Tk()
root.title(name) # name passed in as an arg

# Creation of the canvas and elements moved into another function
draw( root, ... )

if not pause:
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
else:
    mainloop()
```